# Why @Configuration class required for @ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint annotation?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.6 version. Can't we use the `@ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint` annotation with `@Component`? I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OnEnabledEndpointCondition must be be used on @Bean methods when the endpoint is not specified
```

I tried a class like below

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id="customendpoint")
@ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint
class MyCustomEndpoint {
      @ReadOperation
      public String method1() { ....... }          
}
```

`@ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint` is working when I create a configuration class and `@Bean` method.

Why Configuration class is required ?
Is there any other way to stop the component exposing the actuator endpoint with out configuration class.

Comment: Does seem a bit janky huh? I suspect you're better off raising a GitHub issue on since the only way someone will be able to answer the 'why' is if they're a spring maintainer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `endpoint` attribute, see [`ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint#endpoint`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/condition/ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint.html#endpoint--)

> `public abstract Class<?> endpoint`
>
> The endpoint type that should be checked. Inferred when the return type of the `@Bean` method is either an `Endpoint` or an `EndpointExtension`.
>
> **Returns:**
>   the endpoint type to check
>
> **Since:**
>   2.0.6
>
> **Default:**
>   `java.lang.Void.class`

Your modified code:

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id="customendpoint")
@ConditionalOnEnabledEndpoint(endpoint = MyCustomEndpoint.class)
class MyCustomEndpoint {
    @ReadOperation
    public String method1() { ....... }          
}
```